# How to send just a single message with out expecting any reply using zmq?

Tags: c++

Is there any way to send a single packet of data to client using zmq library? I have tried with PUB/SUB and REQ/REP but for PUB/SUB way the publisher needs to stay alive until the subscriber connects which means that it has to be in an infinite loop. And for REQ/REP way, the server should not expect any reply back. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want PUSH/PULL sockets.

More info: http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html

In fact, in the past I have preferred PUSH/PULL since REQ/REP requires a response for each request, which I find too restrictive.